# Check if a remote machine is in a Veritas cluster

Tags: linux, scripting, cluster

How can I verify that a remote machine is part of a Veritas cluster?

I just created the following ssh command to verify if the remote machine is
a VRTS cluster or a Linux availability Red Hat cluster

```
 LinuxTSR=198.23.12.5
 ssh LinuxTSR "ls /usr/sbin/clustat /opt/VRTS 2>/dev/null" | wc -l
```

If I get number that is different from 0, it is a VRTS or Red Hat cluster. But this approach isn't so elegant. Please help me to find more elegant way in order to verify if the remote machine is in a cluster.

Comment: Can you just use `[ -e /usr/sbin/clustat ] || [ -e /opt/VRTS ]`?  (I don't have a way to check, but I believe this should be equivalent to your check.)  Test by appending `&& echo "in cluster"`.

Answer (score 0):

An elegant solution is perhaps "ansible"

I have no way to check with "a veritas cluster", but :

```
ansible yourhost -m setup
```

- gather a list of facts from your host.
- In this list, check if you have something about "veritas",
- then you can filter to get only the fact about veritas :

  ansible yourhost -m setup -a 'filter=yourmagic'

of course replace "yourmagic" with the keywork found